# Decoding http link in .NET

Tags: javascript, .net, html, decoding

I am opening a page from my javascript and passing variable to it like below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(what) {
            var valu = what.value;
            var w = window.open("playaudio.aspx?" + what.value);

            return false;
        }
```

Now on my playaudio.aspx i am doing this to decode back the %2f and %3f etc into / and ?

```
string FilePath = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString.ToString());
```

but the problem is that the string FilePath remains unchanged . Any advice on how to change the %2f into / .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because URLs are not HTML encoded.

You need `UrlDecode`.

Answer (score 1):

See [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) - I believe that's what you're after.